# How do I remove stopwords from a list using a text file

Tags: python, editor

I'm trying to remove stopwords using a text file that includes my own stop words and trying to make a new list without stopwords in them. However, the new list does not remove the stopwords.

```
def remove_stopwords(parametera):
 stopwords = open('myownstopwords.txt')
 stopwords_list = stopwords.readlines()
 new_list = []
 for parametera in stopwords_list:
     if parametera not in stop_list:
         new_list.append(parametera)
     stopwords.close()
     new_list.close()
 print(new_list)
```

Any ideas on fixing it? Do I have to list out all the stopwords from the text file or can I just import it?

Comment: why are you trying to use the `close` method on a list? `new_list.close()`

Comment: sorry, what is the content of `stop_list`? by the code, seems you want to add words in `stopwords_list` into `new_list` if it exists on `stop_list`. i saw no removal...

Comment: i was trying to add words that are not in the myownstopwordst.txt to the new_list. So the new_list should not have any stopwords in them.

Comment: the `return` statement is breaking what you want to do, it will stop at the first loop iteration, and the next lines are not executed

Comment: i have removed the return but it prints out a new list with nothing inside?

Comment: when you parse the text file, each line may contain a linebreak, you have to `strip()` it

Comment: A `list` does not have a `close()` method. So, the program is likely to be terminated when `new_list.close()` is encountered. Moreover, your program is badly indented. `stopwords.close()` should be at the same level as `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code that accepts more than one variables:

```
def remove_stopwords(*args):
    with open('myownstopwords.txt','r') as my_stopwords:
        stopwords_list = my_stopwords.read()
        new_list = []
        for arg in args:
            if str(arg) not in stopwords_list:
                new_list.append(arg)
            else:
                pass # You can write something to do if the stopword is found
            my_stopwords.close()
    print(new_list)


remove_stopwords('axe','alien','a')
```

Here is the code with only one variable:

```
def remove_stopwords(param):
    with open('myownstopwords.txt','r') as my_stopwords:
        stopwords_list = my_stopwords.read()
        new_list = []
        if str(param) not in stopwords_list:
            new_list.append(param)
        else:
            pass # You can write something to do if the stopword is found
        my_stopwords.close()
    print(new_list)


remove_stopwords('axe')
```

Code to accept list:

```
def remove_stopwords(params):
    with open('myownstopwords.txt','r') as my_stopwords:
        stopwords_list = my_stopwords.read()
        new_list = []
        for param in params:
            if str(param) not in stopwords_list:
                new_list.append(param)
            else:
                pass # You can write something to do if the stopword is found
    my_stopwords.close()
    print(new_list)
```

remove_stopwords(['axe','a'])

I removed the redundant `return` statement and the `new_list.close()` as lists cannot be closed and got rid of the `for` loop.

EDIT: for supporting lists, I just added a for loop to loop over the parameter list provided

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, when writing a question in future, be more clear with what you want to achieve and include **all** variables and sources linked to your query.

I  would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to guide you to writing a clear question

Comment: Hi thanks however i tried the code it prints out all the stopwords however it also prints the new list with stopwords still inside?

Comment: @user10272359 yes I have updated my answer just remove the print(stopwords_list) line. I used that for testing purposes

Comment: Hi sorry but removing the print(stopwords_list) only help in removing the printed list. The function still does not work as when using the function the stopwords still appear when i print out the new list?

Comment: yes it is working as intended. However, what is the asterix in def remove_stopwords(*args) mean? i tried changing to another parameter but it gives me back a positional argument?

Comment: @user10272359 *args allows you to pass a variable number of arguments to a function, So in your case, you can pass more than one parameters to the function.  Read this link: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/. If it worked, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Hmmm what if i only one 1 variable? i have tried using a .txt file and chagning it to a list >> remove_stopwords(" title of file") but it does not work. And how do i accept a answer? sorry im new to this website and thanks for the answers

Comment: @user10272359 if you want one variable, just pass one to the function. Click the green arrow to accept :)

Comment: Thanks you have been helpful ! :) one last thing. What if i just want def remove_stopwords(args) without the asterisk? Is this one variable? Sorry just started coding if i am asking something stupid :o

Comment: @user10272359 It's fine I have updated the answer. Hope this helps :) . If this works for you, please accept the answer thanks :)

Comment: Sorry to ask again but i want to use this function to help remove stopwords in a list. I am unable to enter remove_stopwords(text_list) even though i converted text_list into a list type? isn't it a paramter?

Comment: Thanks alot Bill !! The help is very much appreciated !!